# Using button to open new view

Tags: android

I have two applications that I want to combine.  One finds the sizes of pipes and one finds the sizes of tubing.  Both these applications work individually but I want to combine them so that when the new application initially gives the user a simple view with two buttons so they can choose whether they want pipe or tubing. Setting up this two button view is easy, but calling the other views associated with the two separate other applications is what I am having problems with.

For example my .java file for the individual applications is something like this:

```
package com.examples.pipe;

import com.examples.pipe.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;


public class pipe extends Activity {



    /**
     * Initialize a bunch of stuff
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /**
         * derived classes that use onCreate() overrides must always call the super constructor
         */
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);

     /**
     * Do a bunch of calculations and post the results in main.xml
     */
```

Similar code for tubing application.  I initially thought that making my com.examples.pipe and com.examples.tubing applications libraries called by a simple button applications would be the best way to do this but could not figure it out (the tictactoe example on the android site seemed much more complicated than what I wanted to do).

I thought I could just make another application, button_call, with the onCreate of this new application calling

```
setContentView(R.layout.button_main);
```

and then use an onClick to call the .xml files in the layout folder for the individual applications I have already written.  Alas, I have not found a way to do this.

I have this application written on Palm Pre (http://www.myappbox.com/search/?q=pipe+and+tube) but am trying to develop it for android though the code is not altogether similar when is comes to calling different views.

Comment: do you want to keep the 'pipes' and 'tubing' applications separate? Or combine it into a single application? With the former, you can still use intents to fire up the corresponding app.

Comment: I want to keep them separate.

Answer (score 2):

You probably are wanting to use multiple activities.

Please refer to [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) and then [Starting An Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#StartingAnActivity) in particular.

To make a long story short, you can think about an activity as similar to a web page. Most of the time when a user clicks on a button in a web browser, that triggers a query (`Intent` in Android) which brings the user to a new page (`Activity` in Android). Your initial screen with the two buttons would then be one activity, and the pipes and tubes sections would be two separate additional activities.

Comment: I have done a lot of work with JavaScript for years (see:www.freecalc.com) but HTML and JavaScript are more straightforward to a novice programer like myself.  I have looked at the links you suggested but will have to review them again.  One of the biggest problems I have is that logically I would think that the res/layout/ folder for a situation like this should have three .xml files in it, one to call each page, unfortunately I have not found any examples that show multiple files in this location and do not understand how to call them in one .java file.

Comment: Yes, each of your activities will inflate a different xml file in res/layout.

Comment: Do I put these xml files in there manually or does Eclipse do that for me and make any associated linkages?

Comment: Try looking at API Demos or other tutorials that use multiple activities.

Comment: Matthew, got the app running using the suggestion from you and slugster below. A few items were giving me much grief and I would assume that many novices like myself run into this.

Comment: Matthew, got the app running using the suggestions from you and slugster below. A few items were giving me much grief and I would assume that many novices like myself run into this. One, You can have more than one java file and the path to these is something like, com.pipetub.PipeTube.java and com.pipetub.Pipe.java.  Two, you can have more than one xml file in the layout directory and these individual xml layouts can be called on onCreate from the different java files.  Three, you declare the other java files in <activity> in the manifest file.

Comment: Matthew, another quandary I am in.  I am trying to call an xml file (a very simple one) off the web then pulling some of the data in it into my application (parsing I guess it is called).  I have looked at the many, many examples of this out there but all seem very complicated for extracting a small amount of data.  In my case only one piece of data.  Do you have any suggestions on some simplified tutorials that concentrate on retrieving a small amount of data via the web, not a whole RSS feed as many of the examples concentrate on?

Comment: Unfortunately xml is fairly difficult to parse. I would suggest looking for tutorials on `XmlPullParser` or the `XmlPullParser` docs on the developer site. You could also post a question with the xml you're trying to parse.

Comment: Is text easier?  I have an option on the web site I am querying to get my response as a simple text line.  I assumed that maybe I could retrieve this page, turn the text into a string, and then use a little Java to split up this string into smaller strings to get the one piece of information I need.  My biggest hurdle would be calling the URL and converting what I get back to a single string.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows.
Make an xml with two buttons i.e piping and tubing
in the java file for the xml, set listener for the buttons.
In the listeners, try starting a new activity.

xml file can be like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#9999FF"
    >
 <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Main Menu" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textSize="15px"
        android:paddingTop="10px" 
        android:paddingBottom="10px"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#9966FF" 
        />

            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Purchase Requisition" android:layout_marginLeft="60px"
                android:layout_height="35px" android:id="@+id/purchaseRequisitonButton" android:layout_marginTop="40px"
            />

            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Purchase Order" android:layout_marginLeft="65px"
                android:layout_height="35px" android:id="@+id/purchaseOrderButton" android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            />



</LinearLayout>
```

Java file for this can be like...

```
package guide.training.iApproval;

import android.accounts.OnAccountsUpdateListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainMenu extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);


        Button purchaseRequisitionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.purchaseRequisitonButton);
        Button purchaseOrderButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.purchaseOrderButton);



        //Listener for the Purchase Requisition button
        purchaseRequisitionButton.setOnClickListener
        (new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
            public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this,guide.training.iApproval.myJava.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        );

      //Listener for the Purchase Order button
        purchaseOrderButton.setOnClickListener
        (new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
            public void onClick(View v)
                {


                }
            }
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: Say the layout xml for the first thing the user sees is mainmenu.xml as you noted above.  The layout xml for my pipe app is pipemenu.xml and that for my tubing app is tubingmenu.xml.  I would instinctively think that all three would be in the layout folder for this new app but them how do you call these views in the Java file?

Comment: But what do I use instead of guide.training.iApproval.myJava ?  In my manifest file I have         <activity android:name="com.examples.pipe"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>  But when I replace guide.training.iApproval.myJava with com.examples.pipe it says that com.examples is not resolved.

Comment: in the java file for the first xml, (Main menu, as you may call it) put the listeners so as to redirect to your specific xml pages (piping and tubing)

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this,piping.class);                     startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 1):

This method worked for me

View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener(){

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button1: 
                  setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
                  break;
            case R.id.button2: 

                setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
                break;
            case R.id.button3: 

                 setContentView(R.layout.layout3);
                 break;
            case R.id.button4: 

                setContentView(R.layout.layout4);
                break;

              }
    }
```

};

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(handler);
findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(handler);
findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(handler);
findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(handler);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the applications separate, use the following to fire the required app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.pkg.address","com.pkg.address.MainActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

In each of your 'pipes' and 'tubing' app, register for the `ACTION_MAIN` intent so that it is launched. Read up on [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).

Comment: Hmm... now this is starting to make more sense, but where do the individual xml files for each the pipe and tubing apps go in the combined app?

Comment: The xml files go in their respective apps. Is your 'combined app' a third one which only contains the buttons (which fire up the other apps)?

Comment: Yes it is. If the xml files go in there respective apps does the combined app find them by searching for a path in <activities>?

Comment: No. As stated in my answer, it uses the package name.

Comment: In the java file:
        /** This happens if Pipe button is clicked, starting separate pipe application */
        public void onPipeButtonClick(View view) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
             intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.pkg.address","com.examples.pipe"));
             startActivity(intent);
        }

Comment: and in the manifest file:          <activity android:name="com.examples.pipe"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: and finally in the main.xml:      <Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:text="Click here for Pipe Data" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:onClick="onPipeButtonClick"  >
    </Button>