# please explain this block of code

Tags: android, eclipse, button

I found this on android developers when i was trying to program a button:[android developers blog: UI framework changes in Android 1.6](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/ui-framework-changes-in-android-16.html)

With Android 1.6, none of this is necessary. All you have to do is declare a public method in your Activity to handle the click (the method must have one View argument):

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {    public void myClickHandler(View target){        
// Do stuff    
}
}
```

And then reference this method from your XML layout:

```
<Button android:onClick="myClickHandler" />
```

can smeone please explain this code to me?  I am a beginner in programming, and I don't know what to put in the //do stuff space? I need to reference another activity so i can open another screen. And do i still need to have an activity and put a block of program in the class? this is the code i am using in the class at the moment. Please tell me if i need to update it to use this method:

```
package com.duncan.hello.world;
import com.duncan.hello.world.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class OtherActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.other);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put what you want to happen when the button is clicked in the `// do stuff` part.

You only need to update your code if you're using a button click handler in this fashion.

You might want to start with something a bit simpler, and perhaps not target Android 1.6.

Comment: @WhammoKablammo ... *I* don't know what you want to do, so how would *I* know?!

Comment: i want it to reference an activity so i can open another screen

Comment: See [here](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/) or [here](http://www.dotnetexpertsforum.com/how-to-open-a-new-activity-from-button-click-in-android-t1322.html) or [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482337/using-button-to-open-new-view) or... etc.